# is there a way to escape hyphen in parentheses?

Tags: regex

Here is what I have `/amp-\b([a-z0-9]+)\b(?<!ad|sticky-ad|iframe|image)/gi`

Here is the example
https://regexr.com/5or67

it works perfectly except this word **amp-sticky-ad**

I want to catch any amp-XXX, except these four:

amp-ad

amp-sticky-ad

amp-iframe

amp-image

Comment: The only place where hyphen has any special meaning is inside square brackets. In parentheses it's literal.

Comment: The problem is that your negative lookbehind is *after* the second word, so it doesn't exclude them from being the second word itself.

Comment: Why do you put `\b` after `-`? It seems redundant at best

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the explanation, I have to find other another way

Comment: @MadPhysicist but without \b it catches too much

Comment: Between `-` and `[a-z0-9]` there has to be a word boundary, you don't need to match it explicitly.

Comment: And `[a-z0-9]+` will naturally end at a word boundary. The only place you need `\b` is after the specific words you're trying to filter, so it filters `ad` but not `ads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a negative lookahead immediately after `amp-`, not after the next word.

```
amp-(?!(?:ad|sticky-ad|iframe|image)\b)([a-z0-9]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/5orc1)